# Set a table's visibility to false when it has no rows (in reporting services)

Tags: reporting-services, report, reportingservices-2005

**Is there a way to set a table's visibility to false, if the table has no rows?**

I want to hide a table in Reporting Services when it has no rows.

Setting NoRows to **=""** isn't sufficient in this case as space is still left for the table, and some of the table's formatting is still visible.

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio / SQL Reporting Services 2005

Comment: I have never experienced this. If there is no data for the table to display, then nothing happens - unless you've filled in the NoRows.
Is there some other value in the table that is not related to the core dataset?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Try setting the table's "Visibility.Hidden" property to this expression:

```
=CountRows() = 0
```

Comment: Should it be =CountRow() == 0

Comment: No, Reporting Service's internal expression language is VB, which just uses a single = for comparison (as well as assignment).

Comment: My expression always seemed to do the opposite of what I expected. No wonder, the expression is setting "Visibility.Hidden" as opposed to "Initial visibility" as the dialog implies. Grrrrr!

Comment: Just solved my problem, and also someone else in my team's problem! Awesome and so damn elegant.

Comment: If you want to use this on an object outside of the tablix/chart e.g. a textbox you need to add the scope, e.g. =CountRows("Physical_Servers")=0 where the dataset is called Physcial_Servers.

Answer (score 20):

Found the answer on my own, it's pretty simple.

I found [this article](http://www.ssw.com.au/Ssw/Standards/Rules/RulesToBetterSQLReportingServices.aspx) which mentions the CountRows() function.

So to set the Visibilty / Hidden property to hide when there are no rows, it's simply

```
= Iif (CountRows() > 0, false, true)
```