# How to hide Tablix in RDLC C#

Tags: c#, rdlc

I have two tablix in RDLC report,

1. Tablix2
2. Tablix3

Tablix2 have 3 rows

1. Row 1 is used to Show Tablix Header
2. Row 2 is used to Show Data
3. Row 3 Containing Tablix3

**Here is Design of both Tablixs**

[image]

My Aim is hidden Tablix3 when there is no data passed to tablix.

**Here is Runtime Image without hiding Tablix3**

[image]

In above Image There is only one detail record for first Purchase no so it will display in RDLC but other purchase No have not details so that will be hidden.

To Hiding Tablix 3 I am using below code in Tablix3 Properties ==> Visibility ==> Show or hide base on an expression Section.

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!DataColumn9.Value),"False","True")
```

but when I run RDLC it's giving me Error

> the hidden expression for the tablix ‘tablix3’ returned a data type
>   that is not valid

I also tried

```
=IIF(Len(Fields!DataColumn9.Value) > 0 ,"True","False")
```

as well as also changed values `"True","False"` to `0 and 1`, but still same Error
I tried a lot but failed to find out where I am wrong

Comment: Did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514043/set-a-tables-visibility-to-false-when-it-has-no-rows-in-reporting-services ?

Answer (score 0):

using this I solved my problem

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!DataColumn9.Value),True,False)
```

In visibility Property it needs boolean value and I was passing string values so that was a Error